# Likes and Shares lost after changing form wordpress domain to my own domain

Tags: wordpress, facebook

I have a client who has a blog which she has slowly grown for the last 2 years.
After moving from: xyz.wordpress.com to xyz.com ALL Facebook Likes and Shares are lost!

I have followed lots of forumposts about this matter/problem but kind find any solution to this.

Is it really possible that there is NO way for this young woman running a travelblog to regain her so hardly earned shares and likes just because she has her own site now?

I understand that all is URL relevant etc, but there must be some way for her to regain this data.

Does anybody know where i could adresse my question directly to facebook if they can/would transfer this data for her?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, you can't.

Once the object has been created on Facebook's side its URL in Facebook's graph is fixed - the Likes and Comments are associated with that URL and object; you need that URL to be accessible by Facebook's crawler in order to maintain that object in the future. (note that the object becoming inaccessible doesn't necessarily remove it from Facebook, but effectively you'd be starting over)

Answer (score 0):

You can not “transfer” likes to a different URL, they are bound to the URL they were made on.

Getting in contact with Facebook won’t help you here either – they don’t do such transfers.

---

The only possible solution is described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#moving-urls

You need to have the `og:url` of your *new* items point to the URL of the corresponding *old* one.

That means, you will need to have access to the old domain as well, so that you can provide the relevant meta data to the FB scraper from there.

If you have the ability to set this up, then you can redirect users who follow a link from a Facebook post to the old address to the new one – either per JavaScript (which the scraper doesn’t care about), or via a server-side redirect, that makes an exception for the scraper, based on its User Agent (see a little bit further down on same page.)